# Kerberos configuration in jBoss AS 7.1

Tags: kerberos, jboss7.x

I am trying to configure Kerberos authentication in Jboss AS 7.1 and I have some troubles configuring the standalone.xml:
Apparently I need to provide full path to *.keytab file, which is not really convenient. 
I have tried to do something like :

```
<module-option name="keyTab" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/my.keytab"/>
```

But it seems that it is not substituting the variable jboss.server.config.dir with it´s value.

Do anyone have an idea what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're on *nix, here.  It's important for you to remember what the keytab *is*: credentials for the service principal that your clients will authenticate to.  Anyone who can access that keytab file can log in as that account, so it's important that you protect it.

In our environment, we protect it by creating a home directory for the account and placing the keytab there.  So assuming the keytab is for DOMAIN\jboss-svc, we log jboss-svc into the *nix machine (our linux machines are joined to the domain) and place the keytab in the service account's home directory (/home/jboss-svc/jboss-svc.keytab).  Then we chmod 600.

Our /etc/init.d/jboss scripts are edited to run jboss under the jboss-svc account, meaning that jboss will be able to securely access the keytab.

With this setup, you can now configure your jboss to look for the keytab at /home/jboss-svc/jboss-svc.keytab.

Answer (score 0):

stupid question but are you in cluster ? if yes so instead of "server" you have to put "domain" jboss.domain.config.dir,

then it is not mandatory to put keytab you can also put pass/login.

there is several way to use SSO with jboss...

and then try to put absolute path ...

then check if JBOSS_DIR is in environment variables... or setted when jboss launched